# Floor function equation $⌊x + 1/2⌋ + ⌊x⌋ = \frac12 x^6$

Tags: polynomials, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So in this floor equation $⌊x + 1/2⌋ + ⌊x⌋ = \frac12 x^6$, I've tried putting $x = n + e$, where $0 \le e < 1$, but I didn't get anything useful. What should be an approach in these situations?

Comment: $x=0$ and $x=\sqrt[3]{2}$ are trivial solutions.  Given the right side of the equation, there really is just a limited number of things to try.

Comment: I think he means $e= \{x\}$ and $n=  ⌊x⌋ $

Comment: Well, you know that the left hand can't exceed $2x+2$ which limits the range considerably.

Comment: Note:  typo in my earlier comment.  Meant to say the left hand can't exceed $2x+\frac 12$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x = n + e$ and consider two cases $e < 0.5$ and $e \geq 0.5$.

- $0\leq e < 0.5$

$\begin{alignat*}{2}
&2\cdot⌊n + e + 0.5⌋ + 2\cdot⌊n + e⌋ = (n + e)^6\\
&2\cdot n + 2\cdot n = (n + e)^6\\
&4\cdot n = (n + e)^6 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)\\
&2\cdot \sqrt{n} = (n + e)^3\\
&(\sqrt{n} + 1)^2 - (n + 1) = (n + e)^6\\
&-(n + 1) = (n + e)^3 - (\sqrt{n} + 1)^2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
\end{alignat*}$

Notice, that LHS is negative, while RHS positive for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>1}$. Hence, we need to consider only $n \in \{0,1 \}$. Considering $n = 0$ and using $(2)$ yields $x = 0$. While $n = 1$ yields $e = 4^{1/6} - 1 < 0.5$, hence $x = 1 +  4^{1/6} - 1  = 4^{1/6}$.

- $0.5\leq e < 1$

The second case can be worked out similarly, but there are no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $[x+{1\over 2}] =[2x]-[x]$
- $2x-1<[2x]\leq 2x$

So you have to solve $$4x-2<x^6\leq 4x$$